# how to call user defined C function in assembly(x86)?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

```
int add(int a, int b)  // C funcion for addition
{
return(a+b);
}
```

we use `extern`  to use `printf` , `scanf`  etc. C library
how to call above add fuction defined in another  *.c  file or *.h file ?

Comment: Depends on the OS, the Processor, 32bit 64bit etc.

Comment: @MichaelPetch linux , intel , x86

Comment: By x86 I assume you mean 32-bit and not 64-bit?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Nasm

Comment: You use `extern` just like calling the _C_ library. You use the 32-bit CDECL calling convention (push parameters right to left onto the stack) and then do the call. You have to add the name of the object from the Nasm code to the linker you are using? (LD?).